# Finding Fault in my solving

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to find the general solution to a differential and also to prove it satisfies the D.E.

$$xy'= y + 2x^3\cdot(\sin^2(y/x))$$

I used the substitution of $u = y/x$. I got $du/\sin^2(u) = 2x dx$ and got $y = -x\mathrm{arccot}(x^2 + c)$

To prove that it is required general solution. I differentiated it and put it in the original D.E.

I got

$$1/(1+(x^2+c)^2) = \sin^2(-\mathrm{arccot}(x^2 +c))$$

Now, when I try to solve the R.H.S  using the identities

$1 + \cot^2(x) = \mathrm{cosec}^2(x)$ and $1/\mathrm{cosec}^2(x) = \sin^2(x)$ I get the same as L.H.S but with the negative sign can you please guide me.

Comment: Please use MathJax. This is tough to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got $$-\cot(u)=x^2+C$$ as the result of integration.

Comment: would  it be u = arccot(-x^2 - C)? and not -arccot(x^2+C)?